# How to get result with sending post a value to my server

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I make an application to Android with web service. My purpose is; I send to one value to my server for getting values of id"s row. After that, I set to my EditTexts one by one in my activity. When User entered with username and password to my app. I recorded his/her id in SharedPreference. Then; I pass to my activity I send to value ( my recorded value. ). But I get nothing. How can I fix it?

My log cat exception :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

My RestApı interface :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/listeleme_düzenle.php") Call<List<result_düzen>> bilgileri_getir(@Field("id") String id);
```

My ManageAll class :

```
public Call<List<result_düzen>> listeleme_düzenle_id_göre(String id){
    Call<List<result_düzen>> z = getRestApi().bilgileri_getir(id);

    return z;

}
```

My activity"s code :

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
     final String old =  settings.getString("id" , null);


        retrofit2.Call<List<result_düzen>>z = ManagerAll.getinstance().listeleme_düzenle_id_göre(old);
        z.enqueue(new Callback<List<result_düzen>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<result_düzen>> call, Response<List<result_düzen>> response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Düzenle " + response.body().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<result_düzen>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Düzenle " + t.toString());
            }
        } );
```

result_düzen class :

```
public class result_düzen {
    private String sifre;
    private String id;
    private String isim ;
    private String eposta ;
    private String cinsiyet ;
    private String telefon_number;
    private String dogum_tarihi;
    private String sehir;
    private String ilce;


    public String getSifre() {
        return sifre;
    }

    public void setSifre(String sifre) {
        this.sifre = sifre;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIsim() {
        return isim;
    }

    public void setIsim(String isim) {
        this.isim = isim;
    }

    public String getEposta() {
        return eposta;
    }

    public void setEposta(String eposta) {
        this.eposta = eposta;
    }

    public String getCinsiyet() {
        return cinsiyet;
    }

    public void setCinsiyet(String cinsiyet) {
        this.cinsiyet = cinsiyet;
    }

    public String getTelefon_number() {
        return telefon_number;
    }

    public void setTelefon_number(String telefon_number) {
        this.telefon_number = telefon_number;
    }

    public String getDogum_tarihi() {
        return dogum_tarihi;
    }

    public void setDogum_tarihi(String dogum_tarihi) {
        this.dogum_tarihi = dogum_tarihi;
    }

    public String getSehir() {
        return sehir;
    }

    public void setSehir(String sehir) {
        this.sehir = sehir;
    }

    public String getIlce() {
        return ilce;
    }

    public void setIlce(String ilce) {
        this.ilce = ilce;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "result_düzen{" +
                "sifre='" + sifre + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", isim='" + isim + '\'' +
                ", eposta='" + eposta + '\'' +
                ", cinsiyet='" + cinsiyet + '\'' +
                ", telefon_number='" + telefon_number + '\'' +
                ", dogum_tarihi='" + dogum_tarihi + '\'' +
                ", sehir='" + sehir + '\'' +
                ", ilce='" + ilce + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Php json output :

```
null .
```

My php code :

```
<?php
include ('ayar.php');

$id = $_POST["id"];




$bak = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from kullanici WHERE id = {$id}" );

$sayı = mysqli_fetch_row($bak);
$değer = mysqli_num_rows($bak);

echo(json_encode($sayı));

?>
```

if I set to id value. İt gives me like :

```
<?php
include ('ayar.php');



$id = 10;


$bak = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from kullanici WHERE id = {$id}" );

$sayı = mysqli_fetch_row($bak);
$değer = mysqli_num_rows($bak);

echo(json_encode($sayı));

?>
```

Result :

```
["10","selam","berkay","1234","Erkek","214214","2153636","bayburt","hatay"]
```

Comment: I think you have an issue with your model can you post the result_düzen class

Comment: ok. I editted now.

Comment: Can you have found any mistake ?

Comment: Do you have the Json result from the server

Comment: Yes. I put it. Sorry late comment , I saw now your comment.

Comment: try to cast your @Field("id") String id) to int and send it

Comment: Sorry duke.  It does not work.